# Symfony UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Symfony 2.6.11 I need base url I use UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL

```
$base_url = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL;
```

and have true, but I need url How I can get base URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate url from the request

```
$baseurl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath();
```

*[UrlGeneratorInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGeneratorInterface.html)* is just an interface that URL generator classes must implement (within symphony). And **ABSOLUTE_URL** is just a constant that trivially used in the parameters to point a method to 
generate an absolute URL